# Insulating Rim Joists Missouri Zone 4 (cold winters and humid summers)

Tags: insulation, basement-insulation

Basement currently has R13 batt insulation installed in rim joist. I was planning on cutting foam board pieces between each joist and spray foam in the nooks.

My question is, should I remove the current R13 batt insulation or install foam board over or would this lead to mold issues?

How should I seal or address the bottom ledge underneath the rim joists? Just long pieces of foam board too? Thanks
[image]

Comment: How much of those cement walls are above four or five feet below ground level?  Insulating the walls to at least five feet below ground level will probably give more bang for the labour and cost than just worrying about the rim.  Unfinished basement and only need 1x4s or 1x6s as studs/spacers to hold insulation.

Comment: Half of the basement is at ground level. The other half is fully in the ground. It's a walkout basement. Has the R13 around entire basement rim joists.

I'll be refinishing the entire basement. I figured this was step 1. I'll be adding 2x4s, maybe more batting, maybe foam board, maybe vapor barrier. Any tips on the process would be appreciated. I was thinking cement/foundation wall, then vapor barrier plastic mil, then foam board, then 2x4s, then drywall? Unless you recommend something else. (I don't want to do spray insulation as it's too messy for me.)

Comment: Your plan sounds good.  You loose heat/need insulation from above to about four or five feet below ground level.  Below five feet insulation tends to loose value for preventing heat lost/not needed as much(can still use).